# Define a specialised version of a protocol method

Tags: swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a protocol with an associated type like the following:

```
protocol Schedulable {
    associatedtype Phase

    var phase: Phase { get set }
    var duration: TimeInterval { get set }
}
```

I have another protocol which defines a method on a generic type constrained to the previous protocol:

```
protocol Performed {
    func perform<S>(_ work: S) where S: Schedulable
}
```

Let's now suppose I need to store and retrieve a schedule to and from the `UserDefaults`. I need any object to conform to the `Codable` protocol in order to serialize all its properties. In particular, I need the associated type of the `Schedulable` protocol to conform to `Codable`. By the way, I do not want to change the `perform(_:)` method to be like

```
func perform<S>(_ work: S) where S: Schedulable, S.Phase: Codable
```

I would rather have another method which constrains the phase. I thought about using the optional protocol methods, but those do not work with Swift structs. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can define overloads with different generic constraints, why not just define both in the protocol?
Depending on if `S.Phase` is `Codable` or not, the "more constrained" method will be called.

```swift
protocol Performed {
    func perform<S>(_ work: S) where S: Schedulable
    func perform<S>(_ work: S) where S: Schedulable, S.Phase: Codable
}

struct Runner: Performed {
    func perform<S>(_ work: S) where S: Schedulable {
        print("phase is not Codable!")
    }
    func perform<S>(_ work: S) where S: Schedulable, S.Phase: Codable {
        print("phase is Codable!")
    }
}
```